# Binding the CheckBox IsChecked Property to SelectedItems Property of a ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, mvvm, data-binding

I struggle with MVVM data binding.

In my Example I have a `ListView` filled with items which contains a `CheckBox` and some other content.

```
<ListView 
   Background="#f0f0f0" 
   Grid.Row="1" 
   ItemsSource="{Binding ListViewCollection}" 
   SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" 
   IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
   BorderThickness="0" 
   Margin="5">
   <ListView.View>
      <GridView>
         <GridView.Columns>
            <GridViewColumn>
               <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                  <DataTemplate>
                     <CheckBox  Tag="{Binding TheValue}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" />
                  </DataTemplate>
               </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding TheText}" Header="#Cell" />
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding TheVoltage}" Header="U[V]" />
         </GridView.Columns>
      </GridView>
   </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

The `ItemSource` of the `ListView` is bound to a `ObservableCollection` of a data class in the ViewModel, as you do in MVVM.

Now I wanted to hook up the `Checkbox.IsChecked` property of each list view item to the parents `ListView.SelectedItems` property to trigger it. Why? Because I want to show/hide a series of data graph. So if `CheckBox` in row one is checked, show graph 1. If `CheckBox` in row 2 is unchecked, hide graph 2 and so on. Something like this:

```
public ListViewItem SelectedItem
    {
        get { return mSelectedItem; }
        set
        {
            if (mSelectedItem!= value)
            {
                mSelectedItem= value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
                if (SelectedItem.IsChecked == true)
                {
                    OxyplotModel.Series[1].IsVisible = false;
                    OxyplotModel.InvalidatePlot(true);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

To trigger this property you have to click twice in the GUI. First check the `CheckBox` and then click again on the row to trigger and hide the graph. But I wanted to trigger `SelectedItems` property right after the `CheckBox` is clicked.

By now I bound a command to the `CheckBox` and pass a parameter to distinguish the check boxes. But as I said, I want to use the property.

Is this possible or do have better ideas to solve my problem?

Comment: When you use bindings `ListView.SelectedItem` won't be of `ListViewItem` type. It's just a container. It will be of the same type as item in your collection. So if `ItemsSource` is bound to `List<MyItemClass>` then `ListView.SelectedItem(s)` will give `MyItemClass` and that should be the type of your bound property

Comment: Yes i know! But that isn't my problem. The SelectedItem is triggered only when clicking on the row, not on the Checkbox!! I know that i have to bind a property to SelectedItem of the same type as the ItemSource. That is clear to me!

Comment: I know that's not your problem hence only comment. As far as I understand your problem is that `ListViewItem` is not selected because `CheckBox` gets focus. Do you want `ListViewItem` to get selected when `CheckBox` is clicked?

Comment: Yes correctly, that is it what i want!!

Comment: I've asked a pretty similar question before, and I think the solution I've got is even more simple than the current answer you've got http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15091716/wpf-get-a-listboxitem-as-checkbox-with-a-template-style-to-synchronize-with-iss

Comment: `public ListViewItem SelectedItem` what on ... you don't ... no.  If `ItemsSource` is bound to a collection of type Foo, then `SelectedItem` will be the instance of Foo that is currently selected in the control.  If you are wrapping your instances in ListViewItems prior to adding them to your OC... no.   The ListView will wrap for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand your problem it's caused by `CheckBox` stealing focus from `ListViewItem`. If you want to select item when `CheckBox` is clicked you can use animation triggered whenever something in `ListViewItem` gets focus which will set `IsSelected` to true

```
<ListView ... 
   ItemsSource="{Binding ListViewCollection}" 
   SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" 
   SelectionMode="Single">
   <ListView.View>
       <!-- removed -->
   </ListView.View>
   <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
         <Style.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="GotKeyboardFocus">
               <BeginStoryboard>
                  <Storyboard>
                     <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0:0:0" Duration="0:0:0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsSelected">
                        <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame Value="True" />
                     </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  </Storyboard>
               </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
   </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

You also need to specify `SelectionMode="Single"` otherwise previous item won't be unselected

**EDIT**

It adds new event trigger to item container style (`ListViewItem`) which will be executed whenever [`GotKeyboardFocus`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.gotkeyboardfocus(v=vs.110).aspx) event occurs. It's [bubbling event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806(v=vs.110).aspx#routing_strategies) meaning it will bubble up the visual tree from any `ListViewItem` child and finally reach `ListViewItem` where it will trigger [`BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.booleananimationusingkeyframes(v=vs.110).aspx) animation which is able to change value of `Boolean` properties. In this case it's not really an animation as it takes 0 seconds but it will set `IsSelected` property (as specified by `Storyboard.TargetProperty`) to true

Comment: Hey dkozi thank you so much. That is the solution. Maybe you can explain me what these xmal tags are doing. Ok i have the solution but i don't understand it.

Answer (score 0):

The selected Item will be the type of the Items which bind to Items source. if Item source is List means selected Item will be Student.

Comment: Can you add more details to you answer. I'm not sure this is enough to solve the problem, although it seems to point in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to post an alternative to achieve this solution with Command and CommandParameter.

In your XAML bind the Command to the Checkbox. Also bind CommandParameter to a value which wil be passed to the Command itself. Please note: Because the ItemSource of the ListView is set to an Observablecollection you have to change to the parent DataContext with

> Command="{Binding ElementName=NameOfListView,Path=DataContext.NameOfCommand}"

to bind the Command from the ViewModel DataContext. Also you can use an [Ancestor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3406166/binding-to-an-ancestor-in-wpf) to get the parent data context.

```
<ListView
   Background="#f0f0f0" 
   Grid.Row="1" 
   ItemsSource="{Binding ListViewCollection}" 
   Name="ListView" 
   IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
   BorderThickness="0" 
   Margin="5">
   <ListView.View>
      <GridView>
         <GridView.Columns>
            <GridViewColumn>
               <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                  <DataTemplate>
                      <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" 
                      Command="{Binding ElementName=ListView,Path=DataContext.HideShowGraph}" 
                      CommandParameter="{Binding TheValue, Mode=OneWay}" />
                  </DataTemplate>
               </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding TheText}" Header="#Cell" />
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding TheVoltage}" Header="U[V]" />
         </GridView.Columns>
      </GridView>
   </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Then in your ViewModel declare a RelayCommand with parameter and a corresponding delegate method.

```
public class ViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public ViewModel()
        {
            HideShowGraph = new RelayCommand<int>(foo => HideShowGraphExecute(foo));
        }

        public ICommand HideShowGraph { get; private set; }

        private void HideShowGraphExecute(int foo)
        {
           //...evaluate foo
        }
    }
```

So if one Checkbox in the ListView is checked the Command is called and the bounded Value of CommandParameter , in this example "TheValue", is passed to the delegate method HideShowGraphExecute. With this value you are able to distinguish the Checkboxes.

Hope it helps too!